# Are these the right capacitors for this optocoupler?

Tags: capacitor, opto-isolator, esp32

I want to sense mains with an ESP32, for that I am planning to use an AC optocoupler and add some capacitors to smooth the signal. This is my schematic:

[image]

`Sense3` and `Sense4` are mains voltage (230V) and `EspSense3` and `EspSense4` are Pulled-Up ESP32 GPIO (3.3v with internal 45k resistor) 
I tried with a DC optocoupler I have (I don't have any AC one yet), and these capacitors seems to work well.
Now I am planning to buy either the [LDA210 (datasheet)](https://www.ixysic.com/home/pdfs.nsf/www/LDA210.pdf/$file/LDA210.pdf) or [IL250 (datasheet)](https://www.distrelec.ch/Web/Downloads/53/_e/vdIL250-253-ILD250-253_e.pdf).

[I did a simulation](http://lushprojects.com/circuitjs/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWECAstIIEwDZsHZNJ8MAOEFMpFAZmQFMBaMMAKAGdzsURMVJls-Xv34QAZgEMANmzosATiGrVsILkpXhBUHvEgsAbgNFhMxnnx0QE-NLRFRoCFgHdO3ZmZTrhUV8lM1bj5%20dX03EKCNVTD-SLBtBECEkRZqbjEXABN5AHsABwAdAEdRcGg8MBosEjAATkxa%20ExGPB1MaAoEkkw8LHTIPBRMe3AWLPdwQKSzHxBMnIKS-QmEbU8A2e4zBbyi0vHNrX41kzMd7L3lw5njyY2Lxf39QjryOCj47RF0eBQ6gGAoHA1QwQYkSB1fAIahgQZcOooCDI-zKVQpd6ib4sXLgcCNHR8AHIRzwPC1TBIIR46gsIA), and it seems that with very small caps it can work. But I am not sure how reliable this simulation is:

[image]

In there I can see that with a 1uF capacitor it will reach 0.8V (the guaranteed LOW in ESP32) in 100ms.

How can I know if these capacitors are going to work for these optocouplers?

[Edit: Adding some expectations as per comments]

Detection speed is not so critical. I would like it to be under 500ms, but it is acceptable anything under 1s

This PCB will be used in Switzerland, `SensX` will be 230VAC. I would like to add some margin, so maybe detect voltages > 180VAC, but it is not that critical as it is usually very stable

Comment: You don't want any capacitor to stretch the zero-crossing pulse

Comment: Thanks @TonyStewartEE75. Why would I want to stretch the zero-crossing? I only want to detect if there are mains (if a bulb is on/off) in the Sens3/Sens4 wires. This is the purpose of the board: https://github.com/crgarcia12/electronics-homeassistant-lightscontroll/tree/main/PCB/schematics-v16-espinside

Comment: Why do you need any capacitors? Your pulses will be 100/120Hz. You could have a 1000Hz timer timer tick that reads the gpio and loads a software down counter if a pulse is discovered. Another suggestion is the use the RMT to capture the inputs. The rmt will capture a number of samples then interrupt (or read it via a timer tick) and your code can determine if there were pulses and how wide they were. The esp32 is fast, has two cores and peripherals that make detecting these slow pulses on the gpio a very low impact process.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Kartman! The reason is that this board will be integrated to HomeAssistant, so I am planning to use ESPHome to make the integration simpler. I will not write C++ by myself (unfortunately) and instead use a yaml config file. I would prefer to solve this in the hardware side then, to make things much simpler

Comment: It looks like a design flaw to add caps for firmware that cannot respond to these IRQ's so the pulses are fat

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 but I am not trying to "detect pulses", I am trying to detect if a bulb is on or off.. For example, If I would have more space in my PCB, I would use a (switching?) power supply instead. I was using the HCPL-3700 before and that worked very well, but it uses a lot of W to detect 230V mains, so I went for this type of optocouplers

Comment: Ok let's step back and define everything  you expect from voltage range , input min current, to load and time delay for on/off.. make a new list in your question.  This may work but overkill on the power if you increase the R pullup

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 very good points! I added that into the question, hope I understood correctly your comment :)

Comment: The LDA210 has a minimum current transfer ratio (CTR) of 300% with a typical value of 8500%, the Input/output R could easily be raised 10x and still meet this criteria and the output increased with small caps for RC >= 50ms.  Looks like a design done by a S/W specialist

Comment: if S/W means software... you got me :S ... I don't have an oscilloscope, but tried to do some simulations to see what caps would I need, but I did not manage to simulate this optocoupler. I used 22u in this first schematic because it was the recommended one by the HCPL datasheet. The LDA is quite hard to get at the moment, so I will probably go for the IL250 (50% CTR)

Comment: I've used a similar schematic with DC opto and diode bridge instead of AC opto, but I replaced one of the 1W resistors with a 10nF cap. Since your opto has a higher CTR you could use a lower value cap. This results in lower dissipation in the resistors. High value resistor like 10 MOhm in parallel with cap to discharge it in case of finger contact.

Comment: Tasmota has the means of coping with the pulses. Else you want the capacitor to form a low-pass filter so having a resistor in series with the opto output will determine the discharge rate and the pullup will determine the charge rate. You should be able to use a smaller value capacitor.

Comment: Thanks @Kartman. I did now some simulations and start understanding a bit more about it. I read the ESP32 datasheet and it says that pull-up resistors are 45k, so as you mention, I need a very small cap actually

Comment: I meant the original designer was a S/W specialist. I can simulate this easily on Falstad's site, but don't have time